# compare multiple array of objects javascript with the value

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, lodash

```
let a = [{
    isMatched: false,
    value: 'red'
}, {
    isMatched: false,
    value: 'green'
}];
let b = [{
    isMatched: false,
    value: 'red'
}, {
    isMatched: false,
    value: 'brown'
}];
let c = [{
    isMatched: false,
    value: 'white'
}, {
    isMatched: false,
    value: 'green'
}];
let d = [{
    isMatched: false,
    value: 'red'
}, {
    isMatched: false,
    value: 'orange'
}];
```

// expected output

```
let a = [{
    isMatched: true,
    value: 'red'
} {
    isMatched: true,
    value: 'green'
}];
let b = [{
    isMatched: true,
    value: 'red'
}, {
    isMatched: false,
    value: 'brown'
}];
let c = [{
    isMatched: false,
    value: 'white'
}, {
    isMatched: true,
    value: 'green'
}];
let d = [{
    isMatched: true,
    value: 'red'
}, {
    isMatched: false,
    value: 'orange'
}];
```

Comment: Can you elaborate more?

Comment: Against which value are you checking ?

Comment: yes all the 4 array needs to be compared with each other based on 'value' if match found need to update isMatched -> true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take a `Map`, check if the map contains a data set with `value` as key and if not add the object to the map or set the stored object's `isMatched` property to `true`, as well as the actual object.

For preventing setting `true` to much the value is changed to `undefined`.

```js
let a = [{ isMatched: false, value: 'red' }, { isMatched: false, value: 'green' }],
    b = [{ isMatched: false, value: 'red' }, { isMatched: false, value: 'brown' }],
    c = [{ isMatched: false, value: 'white' }, { isMatched: false,  value: 'green' }],
    d = [{ isMatched: false, value: 'red' }, { isMatched: false, value: 'orange' }];

[a, b, c, d].forEach((m => a => a.forEach(o => {
    if (m.has(o.value)) {
        o.isMatched = true;
        const temp = m.get(o.value);
        if (temp) {
            temp.isMatched = true;
            m.set(o.value, undefined);
        }
    } else {
        m.set(o.value, o);
    }
}))(new Map));

console.log(a);
console.log(b);
console.log(c);
console.log(d);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can combine all the arrays in one and then count the values that appear more than one:

```
let combinedArrays = a.concat(b, c, d);
countValues = {}

combinedArrays.forEach(function(v) {
  if (isNaN(countValues[v.value])) {
    countValues[v.value] = 1;
  }else {
    countValues[v.value] += 1;
  }
})
```

You can then iterate through each of the arrays and check `if countValues[value] > 1` then set `isMatched` to `true`